# Trim white space and optional quotes from string RegEx

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx that is supposed to trim optional white space or quotes from the beginning and end of a string.

```
/(^[\s|"]*)(.*)([\s|"])/
```

I have demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/7K8Y8c/1).

It works for the following:

```
    "Web_1,art_1"
```

but breaks for the following:

```
    Web_1,art_1
```

I can't get the optional quote at the end to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[\s"]*|[\s"]*$
```

Replace each match with a blank string

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7K8Y8c/4)**

**Explanation:**

- `^[\s"]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of either a white-space or a `"` at the start of the String
- `|` - OR
- `[\s"]*$` - matches 0+ occurrences of either a white-space or a `"` at the end of the String

Answer (score 1):

Add a star at the end just like at the beginning. Then make the `.*` non-greedy with `.*?`: you want any trailing spaces or quotes to be matched by the trailing group, not the inner one.

```
/(^[\s|"]*)(.*?)([\s|"]*)/
```

Also, for symmetry add a `$` anchor at the end, and get rid of the `|`s. Alternation bars don't belong inside `[...]` character classes.

```
/(^[\s"]*)(.*?)([\s"]*$)/
```

There's no real reason to have the outer capture groups, either.

```
/^[\s"]*(.*?)[\s"]*$/
```